# Cannot set lockscreen in Windows 10

Tags: powershell, registry, lockscreen

I'm attempting to set a lockscreen image in Windows 10 using a Powershell script.

This appears to work fine on my Windows 10 Business PC, but when I attempt to use it on a Windows 10 Pro device the registry key is created successfully, but when the screen is locked only the default 'cave' image displays rather than the new lockscreen.

I have also attempted this using the PersonalizationCSP feature but I understand this will now work on Windows 10 Pro.

Does anybody have an alternate solution, or able to give me a pointer as to what I'm doing wrong here?  Is it even possible to automate lockscreen updates in Windows 10 Pro?  Much appreciated.

Code example below:

$filepath = "c:\LockscreenImages"
$RegKeyPath = "HKLM:\SOFTWARE\Policies\Microsoft\Windows\Personalization"

$newlockscreen = $filepath + "lockscreen.jpg"

if(!(Test-Path $RegKeyPath)) {
Write-Host "Creating registry path $($RegKeyPath)."
New-Item -Path $RegKeyPath -Force | Out-Null
}
Set-ItemProperty -Path $RegKeyPath -Name "LockscreenImage" -Value $newlockscreen

Tried a number of approaches, updating

HKLM:\SOFTWARE\Policies\Microsoft\Windows\Personalization
or
HKLM:\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\PersonalizationCSP

Success of this seemed to vary based on the Windows edition used.  On the Windows 10 Pro devices intended for deployment, this was successful in updating the registry keys but the lockscreen did not change.

Thanks for any assistance.

- Stephen

Comment: Even after a reboot the lock screen does not appear ?

Comment: Correct - the lockscreen does not appear after a reboot.

After updating the Personalization registry entry on most Win10 installations I've tried, the lockscreen update appears instantly, even without a reboot.

On Win10 Pro, it never changes at all, regardless of reboot.